# How to resize image in PHP with new dimensions?

Tags: php

Can anyone help me resize an image in core php. Can anyone write code for me to resize an image using core php. Here is my code:

```
public function add_images(){
        $image=$_FILES['file'];
        if(!empty($image)){
            if($image['error']==0){
                $imgName = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
                $ext = $imgName['extension'];
                $rand=mt_rand(5,1000000000).'.'.$ext;
                $destination = base_path() . '/public/images/ListingImages/';
                if(move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $destination.$rand)){
                    echo "moved"; die; 
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This code works fine for me. But when the user uploads an image it should be resized to 300x300.

Comment: the link you provided to many answers but not working any answer can you write code rishi for me!

Comment: Do you want the images cropped or stretched?

Comment: I want imge tio be resized if user upload image in 100*100 i want to resized in 300*300 . Please help if you have code.